# parsing unstructured data using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, parsing, pyspark, raw-data

I am new to Spark. I am trying to parse unstructured data with the below format.

**The entire dataset is in a single line**.

Each line/record is delimited by a special character **~$|** and each column of the record is delimited by tab space.

So how can I parse this and convert it into a data frame?

```
Raj India 1000 ~$| John Canada 2000 ~$| Steve USA 3000 ~$| Jason USA 4000
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `spark.read.text()` method and In option keep your custom **`lineSep`**

```
spark.read.option("lineSep", '~$|').text('<filepath>').withColumn("value",regexp_replace(col("value"),'\n','')).show()
#+------------------+
#|             value|
#+------------------+
#|   Raj India 1000 |
#| John Canada 2000 |
#|   Steve USA 3000 |
#|    Jason USA 4000|
#+------------------+
```

Once dataframe is created then use **`split`** function on value column to create new columns to the dataframe using either `.getItem`,`element_at` functions.